# Posting Multiple Documents to CouchDB with curl

Tags: json, curl, couchdb

I am using the following curl command to upload data to CouchDB:

```
 curl -d @abcd.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://@localhost:5984/database/_bulk_docs
```

The file contains multiple JSON documents and is valid JSON.

The response I get is: `{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Request body must be a JSON object"}`

I have studied other answers to similar questions but don't seem to be able to find the reason for the error.

(The file does not have a 'BOM' as far as I can see.)

I am running on Windows 10.

I have tried using the RESTClient addon in Firefox with the same result.

Comment: Please, show the example content of abcd.json file. Are the contained jsons supposed to be separated documents in couchDB?

Answer (score 2):

To solve this I have found that one needs an added structure in the input file, nl. an additional:

```
 {       
 "docs":
```

before the first `"["` of the first JSON document in the file(naturally with closing `"}"`) then everything works.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

[This](http://www.greenacorn-websolutions.com/couchdb/export-import-a-database-with-couchdb.php) post jogged my thinking.